# How to classify correctly from TENSORFLOW LITE app using INTENT CAMERA?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-android

I tested my fine tuned model using REAL TIME TF-LITE Cllasifier DEMO APP, it showed pretty good results. But when I test same model with Intent Camera Picture ( one at a time ) it shows pretty bad result( 0.06 or 0.04 almost every time ) . I am attaching Intent code , kindly check for errors.

onActivityResult :

```
Bitmap bit = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
imgview.setImageBitmap(bit);

 Bitmap bitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit,224,224,false);
 result_textbox.setText(classifyFrame(bitmap));
 bitmap.recycle();
```

classification code is same to same as in TF-LITE Classifier App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the applyfilter() function. Follow this thread

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18894